# The method getDrawingCache() returns null depends on portrait or landscape mode

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, drawing, imageview

If I start my App in Landscape-Mode the getDrawingCache() returns the Bitmap I need, after changing the orientation to portrait mode (while app is running), getDrawingCache() returns null. 
If I start my App in Portrait-Mode the getDrawingCache() returns the Bitmap I need, doesn't matter which orientation.

Whats happening here?? What is the difference between starting the App from Landscape or Portrait? Why does it change the getDrawingCache() method?

Here are my code:

```
mPlaceHolderBitmap = null;
if (imageView.getDrawable() != null) {
    imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    imageView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    mPlaceHolderBitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache(true);
}
```

I also tried to use getDrawingCache without boolean or without calling buildDrawingCache but always the same.

Answer (score 0):

when you change orientation that time onConfigurationChanged() called did u used this method???

Comment: if you had allowed for orientation change on your manifest then when you change orientation that time point goes to this method and where you wrote code to fetch drawing cache?? oncreate() or in onResume()??

Comment: this method is called after 2 seconds. At first a small-sized-image is shown. after the 2 seconds it loads the high-quality image. While it loads the high-quality the small-sized-image is replaced with this drawingCache. Called 2 seconds after onCreate.

Comment: What is the difference if i open the App in landscape or in portrait? i think there shouldn't be a difference! Why does it work when i start the App in portrait?

Comment: no there is on difference in landscape or in portrait but when you switch from landscape to portrait and your app is in foreground that time onConfigurationChanged() called if you dont want this i hv a better solution put "screensize" attribute in manifest

Comment: do you mean support-screen? i do not (and i can't) handle onConfigurationChanged(). i think the buildDrawingCache() method of View end up in a OutOfMemory? Because this is the only way it can be null?! http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.buildDrawingCache%28boolean%29

Comment: yes i support orientation! What do you mean with attribute "screensize"?